# Memory savings of Python Tkinter GUI vs PyQT

Tags: python-3.x, qt, tkinter, tk-toolkit

**BACKGROUND:** 
It's important to consider memory usage of applications on ARM computers like the Raspberry Pi.  When programming with Python, there are several GUI choices.  A couple of the most popular are QT and TK.  The Raspberry Pi 2 and 3 are limited by 1-Gbyte RAM, and 32-Gbyte max USB memory storage, per stick.  They also have a much slower RISC (ARM) processor compared to popular desktop or laptop computers.  Still, it's "enough" to run applications, even many GUI applications at a time if they use conservative programming techniques.  I'm figuring that if a user stuck to TK based applications (Python-Tkinter-GUI) with the Raspberry Pi, then there wouldn't be nearly the number of difficulties.

**Q:** Does anyone have any statistics on this ... by using Tkinter instead of PyQT for GUI program development with the intended user being on a Raspberry Pi version 2 or 3 ...

**Performance ratios, programming with Tkinter vs PyQT:**

1. Size of Program in storage
2. Size of Program executed in RAM
3. Speed of Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter based GUI should be smaller on the disk and RAM but has less capabilities and may not suite your needs depending on what you need. tkinter is best for a small, simple gui. it will have no problems running a fair sized document.